# Why is my CSS rule changing multiple things unintentionally?

Tags: css, wordpress

In an attempt to change the color of the "Subscribe" button I added the below CSS via the edit CSS plugin.

```css
#mc_embed_signup .button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

This bit of code accomplishes its desired purpose, but also changes many other things on my website including, but not limited to: header, footer, H1 text, H2 text, etc.

Why is this bit of code wreaking so much havoc?

Comment: Because you are targeting every element with a class of ".button" that is inside your container with id "#mc_embed_signup" thus ANY element with class ".button" will be affected - if you've got H1, H2 etc with the same class then it will be affected... if you only want to target ONE element then give it either it's own class or ID. If you give it an ID you must make sure it is unique within your DOM.

Comment: The button in question is the subscribe button in the sidebar here: http://messianicschool.com/about-us/contact/

I thought that the .button was a part of it's id, but I guess not?

(I apologize for my ignorance. I'm a beginner at CSS)

Edit: after I inspection I see that "#mc_embed_signup" is the id and ".button" is the class.

Comment: change your CSS to `input#mc-embedded-subscribe { styles }` and see what happens :)

Comment: That code shouldn't be changing any other elements. I guess the real question is, what else is that plugin changing? It might be worthwhile to "inspect element" (right click menu) of one of these things that is changing when it shouldn't and see what's happening.

Comment: This isn't regarding a plugin of any sort. I'm using an embed code from mailchimp to embed a signup form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular bit of CSS is probably not what's screwing up the rest of your site.

Your `#mc_embed_signup .button {}` selector is fine. `#mc_embed_signup` is the id of the `div` element that wraps the MailChimp signup form, `.button` is the class of the button, and your selector means "apply the following styles to anything with a class of `button` inside the element with an id of `mc_embed_signup`."

Since there's only one button inside that form, though, and it has its own `id`, you could also accomplish the same thing by writing `#mc-embedded-subscribe {}`.

In any case, it's probably another error in your CSS that's causing the rest of your site's styling to go haywire. Look carefully for any unclosed curly braces or missing semicolons.

Comment: "Look carefully for any unclosed curly braces or missing semicolons."

I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i would also suggest trying to work out your naming conventions more and think about workflow. having to rely on an ID to style a class as vague as .button is a bad way of working, as you could then later on want to style .button to do something else and inadvertently break it through the rest of the site. if you NEED to add styling to .button but it needs to be specific to that page then your best bet is to add another class called something more specific to do with what the button does i.e. .subscribe-button and then style that instead.

Try and stay away from styling with ID as much as you can as its really not very forgiving when it comes to editing later on.

p.s. did you fix your issue?

Comment: that was supposed to be a comment, not an answer... sorry =/

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it. I've got deadlines to meet for other projects over the next couple of days, but I'm going to tackle it before the end of the week.

I'll leave an update on whether it worked or not soon!